# How can I speed up my SVN to commit?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a question with Tortoise SVN. How can I commit the thousands of files to SVN? Is there any batch file or script or any command which will commit all the data?

How can I speed up my SVN to commit?

Comment: Just commit a whole folder, instead of each file?

Comment: Does `Select All` -> right-click -> `Add....` and then `Commit...` not work for you?

Comment: Thanks for reply.there is huge data like 80000 and more file so i am getting error. connection failure. if i try to commit in bunch of 1000 files it works fine.

Comment: @user905etc, If you are having trouble due to connection failures, that really should be mentioned in your question.

Comment: sorry its my mistake. but it woks fine for 1000 files

Answer (score 2):

To speed the transfer up (regardless of number of files), make sure that you use the svn:// protocol, not the slower http:// protocol.

Comment: I don't think that this is what the OP was asking

Comment: But still, an answer to a related question, of which I am thankful. +1